# ActiveRecord relations inside serialized hash - best way to handle the join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, hash, foreign-key-relationship

I have a weird situation. I have two models ("object" and "asset") and a polymorphic join table (things other than objects can relate to assets). The "object" has a serialized hash, where some of the values are ID numbers (foreign keys, although not marked as such in the db) for "assets", and I would like to properly track which "assets' are being used in which "objects" in that join table, and I'm not sure of the best way to go about it.

The main purpose of this set up is to allow us to list all the objects, etc, that use a given asset. Many of the other things that use assets also have such a serialized hash situation.

What I think I need to do is just update the entries in the join table based on a simple scan of the hash for the ID values, and, from there, just treat it like any many-to-one situation.

But, I also wonder if there's a better way to go about it?

(I can't really change the architecture - the serialized hash is actually for use in a completely different codebase, and while I technically don't have to use the join table, I'd prefer to not add *another* way to do the book-keeping on this kind of relationship.)

PS - Rails on Postgres.

Comment: I think you're stuck doing this the dumb slow stupid way: pull the YAML out of the database, parse it, pull out the `id`s you need, go back to the database with a list of `id`s. I suppose you could write a YAML-to-JSON converter in PL/pgSQL if you wanted but I think you're stuck doing it by hand like a caveman.